# System.Transactions.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace throwing TypeInitializationException

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, c++-cli, windows-8

Seems related to [Strange exception coming out of OdbcConnection.Open()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893643/strange-exception-coming-out-of-odbcconnection-open) but I'm not sure.

I recently switched over to Win8 and hadn't run this app since.  I'm using VS2012, but the projects have not been upgraded.  The dump of the exception looks like this:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: 
 The type initializer for 'System.Transactions.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace' threw an exception. ---> 
 System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> 
 System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Uri' threw an exception. ---> 
 System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.UriParser' threw an exception. ---> 
 System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Runtime.Versioning.BinaryCompatibility' threw an exception. ---> 
 System.ArgumentException: String cannot be of zero length.
Parameter name: frameworkName
   at System.Runtime.Versioning.BinaryCompatibility.ParseFrameworkName(String frameworkName, String& identifier, Int32& version, String& profile)
   at System.Runtime.Versioning.BinaryCompatibility.ParseTargetFrameworkMonikerIntoEnum(String targetFrameworkMoniker, TargetFrameworkId& targetFramework, Int32& targetFrameworkVersion)
   at System.Runtime.Versioning.BinaryCompatibility.ReadTargetFrameworkId()
   at System.Runtime.Versioning.BinaryCompatibility.get_AppWasBuiltForFramework()
   at System.Runtime.Versioning.BinaryCompatibility..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.Versioning.BinaryCompatibility.get_TargetsAtLeast_Desktop_V4_5()
   at System.UriParser..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Uri..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem..ctor()
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.GetConfigSection()
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_Sources()
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.Initialize()
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.get_Switch()
   at System.Transactions.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.get_Current()
   at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.DataAccessAdapterBase.InitClass(IComPlusAdapterContext comPlusContextHost, IPersistenceInfoProvider persistenceInfoProvider)
   at ZAA.FarmInterface.bw_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) in d:\eddynet\projects\zaa\zaacmdline\farminterface.cpp:line 482
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRunWorkerCompleted(RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.AsyncOperationCompleted(Object arg)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

App.config looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>

    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

      <dependentAssembly> <!--For LLBLGen -->
        <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.11.0"/>

      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>

  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I've tried rebuilding, to no avail.

Tried adding an empty  section to app.config.

---

Looking at the manifest off the .exe in ILDASM, I found this, which looks odd:

```
.assembly zaacmdline
{
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute::.ctor(string) = ( 01 00 00 01 00 54 0E 14 46 72 61 6D 65 77 6F 72   // .....T..Framewor
                                                                                                    6B 44 69 73 70 6C 61 79 4E 61 6D 65 10 2E 4E 45   // kDisplayName..NE
                                                                                                    54 20 46 72 61 6D 65 77 6F 72 6B 20 34 )          // T Framework 4
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Security.SecurityRulesAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Security.SecurityRuleSet) = ( 01 00 01 00 00 ) 
  .permissionset reqmin
         = {[mscorlib]System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermissionAttribute = {property bool 'SkipVerification' = bool(true)}}
  .hash algorithm 0x00008004
  .ver 0:0:0:0
}
```

the TargetFrameworkAttribute is certainly fubar, compared to the working machine.  How do I fix it?

Comment: Maybe I need to repair my .net install somehow?  But its integrated into Win8

Comment: There's something wrong with the [TargetFramework] attribute in the startup assembly.  Maybe you had an old beta on the machine?  Rebuild first.

Comment: clean RTM OS install. Reused my source code directory though. I did do a lot of rebuilding, including deleting some Release directories. Rebuild what?

Comment: Same codebase on a different win8 machine (upgrade instead of clean install) works.  All my other apps using the same assemblies here work as well.

Comment: Possible answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/13315940/1810905

Comment: Please provide that as an answer DSN_SLO

Comment: I had capitalization problems in my app.config file.  Example.  "connectionstrings" should be "connectionStrings".  That seemed to solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comment about seeing the link below should fix the problem.
[App's .exe file missing .NET TargetFramework, but only on clean builds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13315940/1810905)

Basically: Delete `C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cpp`

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked DSN_SLO to submit it as an answer.

Comment: Configuration System Failed to Initialize
See this link also, ran into a case where I had to edit the .cpp file, deleting it was not enough (it would get re-created wrong)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315940

Comment: This really works. I spent 2 days to solve this! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

(From comments above)

I had capitalization problems in my app.config file. Example: "connectionstrings" should be "connectionStrings". That seemed to solve the problem for me.

Hope this helped others.

Answer (score 0):

Just Clear App.Config file and rebuild your project

App.Config should be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup> 
</configuration>
```