# Exception on SqlConnection->Open();

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, clr

I'm having an exception thrown on the following code in C++ using /clr

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Data::SqlClient;

// The following code is below in a method, it's within Static library 
// (.lib) project that's being called by my main (.exe)
{    
    SqlConnection^  myConnection;
    myConnection = gcnew SqlConnection("{connection string}");
    try
    {
        myConnection->Open(); // this line throws the error
    }
    catch(Exception^ exp)
    {
    }
}
```

The exception that is throws is below: 
[image]

I've done mass amounts of searching, and have tried a few fixes, including but not limited to:

- updating vcxproj to include 
  `<PropertyGroup Label="Globals"><TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>`
- Modified/Deleted `C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cpp`

I'm at a loss to what to try next, and when I create a new C++ CLR project and try from within the int main function and it doesn't through this exception (the projects I'm using are old legacy libraries and solutions that I'm trying to migrate to VS 2015)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Stack Trace:**

```
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.get_Current()
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetFromTransactedPool(Transaction& transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at ExecuteSqlQuery(basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<char>\,std::allocator<char> >* strQuery, basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<char>\,std::allocator<char> >* strDatabase, vector<char \* \*\,std::allocator<char \* \*> >* lstResults, Int32* numFields) in c:\myvisualstudio\libraries\csqlhisto\csolar.cpp:line 552
```

*Line 552 of csolar.cpp is `myConnection->Open()`

**Inner Exceptions**
[image]

Comment: The hint is in the inner exception "Configuration system failed to initialize". Could you please post the complete exception stack trace, including those of the inner exception(s)?

Comment: Check your app.config for ill-formed XML.

Comment: It's a c++ console application, it doesn't have an app.config. And I've tried dozens of options within app properties, thus far to no avail.

Comment: Can you post the whole text of the line "FrameworkName cannot have less..." (Inner Exceptions)?

Comment: It looks like you having [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12537303/21567) as well.

Comment: Christian, I've already attempted to delete the Local/Temp AssemblyAttributes file, but it did not resolve the issue, and continued to throw the same exceptions.